# Is this CPU Dual LGA 2011?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i7

I want to get [this CPU](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116901) for [this motherboard](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182348) but I don't know how to tell if they support each other. Can you tell me how to tell if they support each other?

Comment: That's an odd combination. Just in case you chose the motherboard by sorting by price and selecting the most expensive one: It's a *server* motherboard. You'd usually use *two Xeon (server) CPUs*, *registered ECC RAM* and *SAS disks* with it. i7's don't support multi-CPU use, so you'd throw away a lot of money.

Comment: @DanielBeck Aha, that's what I needed to know.

Comment: @DanielBeck So do I want one of [these](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822135022CVF) HDDs?

Comment: Well, it's supported at least. As you can see from the price and specs, these are not your typical home and office PC components. (and the board won't even fit in most chassis anyway!) Not to discourage you from building things yourself, but have you taken a look at pre-built servers (e.g. from HP or Dell), at least to get an idea what the components used in such computers are?

Comment: "the SUPERMICRO MBD-X9DR3-F-O server motherboard supports dual Intel Socket R (LGA 2011) ***Xeon*** CPUs"

Comment: **They are entirely different sockets.  LGA1150 does not exist in a dual-cpu configuration.**  I don't believe this to be a real question and even if it is the specifications of either product would indicate clearly ( in either specification ) the other one wasn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the CPU socket type (i.e. they must match). The motherboard you chose has a `Dual LGA 2011` socket type, while the CPU has a `LGA 1150` socket type.

As Daniel correctly pointed out in his comment, that motherboard is meant for server use. So at this point I don't know if you want to build a server (and so you would have to change CPU) or if you want a home PC (and therefore you should change motherboard).

Comment: Yes, I do want to build a server

Comment: @user72323 then I would suggest you have a look at the Xeon CPUs